# Inject Context Ef core to Worker Service project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-service-worker

i want inject my contect to project and use context in workers :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<XContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(
                            hostContext.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Connection"],
                            serverDbContextOptionsBuilder =>
                            {
                                var minutes = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalSeconds;
                                serverDbContextOptionsBuilder.CommandTimeout(minutes);
                                serverDbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                            });
                    });
                    //services.AddTransient<XContext>();
                    //services.AddTransient<XContext>();
                    services.AddScoped<XContext>();

                    //workers
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker1>();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();
                });
    }
```

workers :

```
     public class Worker1: BackgroundService
        {
            private readonly ILogger<Worker1> _logger;
    
            private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    
            private readonly TookoContext _uow;
    
             
    
            public Worker1(ILogger<Worker1> logger, IConfiguration configuration, XContext uow)
            {
                _logger = logger;
                _configuration = configuration;
                _uow = uow;
            }
   // ...
}
```

but i have this error :

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating>
> the service descriptor ServiceType:
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton
> ImplementationType: Worker1': Cannot consume scoped service 'XContext'
> from singleton

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `IServiceProvider` into the hosted service instead, and then when you need an `XContext`:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.GetRequiredService<XContext>();
    // ...
}
```

`DBContext` is intended to be short-lived, so don’t be tempted to create one when your service starts and keep it around for the lifetime of the service. You should instead create, use briefly, then dispose of them, as and when needed.

In the example above, the scope will handle disposing the context; you do not need to - and shouldn’t - do it yourself.

Comment: And **definitely do not** be tempted to register your Context as a singleton!

Comment: Can you show what your constructor for your service looks like now. Also remove this; it's already taken care of with `AddDbContext()`: `services.AddScoped<XContext>();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the AddDbContext lifecycle in a second parameter.

In the worker's opinion, this type of approach is completely valid, unless you want to simulate sequential executions in a loop with different scopes.

```
services.AddDbContext<T>(opt => {...}, ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
```